# Finding the difference when substracting two dictionaries in both ways in one operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
new = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
old = {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
added = new.keys() - old.keys()
if added:
  print('{} keys have been added'.format(len(added)))
removed = old.keys() - new.keys()
if removed:
  print('{} keys have been removed'.format(len(removed)))
# added, removed = minus_dict(new, old)
```

I have to do subtraction operation twice. Does minus_dict function exist? I mean how do I find added and removed in more efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

Use the XOR operator if a single set suffices:

```
>>> old.keys() ^ new.keys()
{'c', 'b'}
```

If that's not good enough, you will have to do two subtractions, or code up an algorithm yourself.

Comment: Well, I guess there are no efficient ways to subtract them in one operation. You have to do it twice. I want to separate the added and removed. All I can think is a quadratic behaviour algorithm. Anyway, I upvote your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @vajrasky: just subtracting twice has linear-time performance.